# Is it possible to "shovel" a persitent akka mailbox?

Tags: akka

I have an AMQP application that has a persistent RabbitMQ queue in the client side and a RabbitMQ queue in the server side. The client always writes in the local persistent queue and those messages are transmited to server using shovel plugin.

```
Producer -> Local Queue  --------- SHOVEL ---------- Remote queue -> Consumer
```

Whether the server is not present the app stills works and shovel does the send when possible. In the other hand the server doesn't require to know the location of the clients becaiuse it consmes always from local queues. I would like to migrate this topology to AKKA using the FilePersistent Mailbox. Is it even possible? Is there something like Federation or Shovel plugin in Akka core libraries.

PS: What I want to achieve is replacing completetly AMQP to get rid of RabbitMQ. It works fine but is another piece of software to install, configure and mantain. I would like to provide all this functionality from my application using just libraries and not another server like RabbitMQ.

Just to clarify a little more what I'm looking to achieve is something like this:

```
Actor1 -> DurableMailBox1  ----Shovel? Federation?---- DurableMailbox2 <- Actor2
```

[EDIT]

It looks like there's no way to communicate directly mailbox to mailbox. The possible topologies that can be implemented with AKKA are these:

```
 Remote Actor1 -> [DurableMailBox1 <- Actor2]
```

Where the arrow can be secured in order to ensure message delivery but is not possible to copy messages from one Mailbox to other Mailbox automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Akka [Remoting](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/remoting.html) and the [Reliable Proxy Pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/contrib/reliable-proxy.html).

> Sending via a ReliableProxy makes the message send exactly as reliable
>   as if the represented target were to live within the same JVM,
>   provided that the remote actor system does not terminate. In effect,
>   both ends (i.e. JVM and actor system) must be considered as one when
>   evaluating the reliability of this communication channel. The benefit
>   is that the network in-between is taken out of that equation.

See [this enhancement](https://gist.github.com/ericacm/5417436) to the ReliableProxy that mitigates the problem with the remote actor system terminating.

Comment: tnks, your answer made me go to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613931 , It looks like I won't be able to replace my RabbitMQ server with AKKA because the Realible Proxy pattern does not persist the messages. In the topology that I have using AMQP+Rabbit I can send messages to nodes that even are not running and my application can crash without danger of lossing messages. When the node becomes available it receives all the messages without hassle. If I use reliable proxy pattern I would need to write code to persist messages and retry them (exactly what shovel does).

Comment: I thought you were going to use the `FileBasedMailboxType` for durability?  See more info here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/modules/durable-mailbox.html

Comment: The problem with using FBMT is that the server won't know the location of client and if I put the FBMT in the server and the server dies, or the WAN is slow, etc etc. the client can't send messages until the server recover.

Comment: Added an edit to the question to show the problematic with the Durable Mailbox and the Reliable Proxy Pattern.

Comment: Every actor has a mailbox.  An actor does not have access to other actor's mailboxes.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the client can't send messages until the server recovers".  That is what the `ReliableProxy` is for.  It keeps retrying until the server comes back up.

Comment: That's the problem. If the server is not present the ReliableProxy will retry, but even with the constant retries if for some reason the client dies at that point I would need to recreate that message. In the topology that I have at this point I write in a persistent local queue (that is always available) and if the client dies and the server dies the message is still there. When the server is back RabbitMQ shovels the messages to another persisten queue in the server. An example of my topology: http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/rabbitmq-with-shovel-plugin/

Comment: You would use persistent mailboxes on both sides (client and server, including reliable proxy)

Comment: I will keep the question open until experimentig with pmailbox and rproxy. I hope being able to return with the results in a couple of days, thanks for the help sourcedelica